# Objeto que tiene varias propiedades, una de ellas es un array, quiero acceder al contenido del array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

```js
const persona = {
    firstname: "María",
    lastname: "Rodríguez",
    birth_date: "1983-04-19",
    education: [
               {course: "LiNUX",
               year: 2017,
               institution: "Universidad 2021", course: "Linux (ADM)", year: 2018,},
               {course: "LiNUX",
               year: 2015,
               institution: "Universidad 2021", course: "Linux (Basic)", year: 2016,},]
};
```

Al siguiente codigo deseo acceder al atributo "education", ahi listar todos los datos del array.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? ¿Ya sabes cómo se recorre un `Array`?¿Has leido la documentación sobre Objetos en JS (asumo que hablas de JS)?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje quieres hacer esto?

Answer (score 2):

Cuando utilizas objetos basta con hacer referencia al nombre de la propiedad a la que quieres acceder, en este caso sería `persona.education`si lo que quieres es listar los datos del array, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
persona.education.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

con el forEach recorres el  array education aunque dependiendo de cómo lo vayas a ocupar, puede que necesites ocupar un for u otro ciclo. eso quedará a tu criterio.

lo otro es que depende del lenguaje de programación se hace de forma un poco distinta. Mi ejemplo está hecho en JavaScript

Comment: es en JavaScript

Comment: si el lenguaje es JavaScript entonces mi solución debería funcionar